# Rails joining has_many relation but also want results with no relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am not sure about the best approach to achieve the following:

We have users belonging to a country. Then we have several categories that can be positioned differently for each country.

I want to get an array with all categories and their position for a given country (order by category_position.position, then category.name). I also want the list to include categories that have no category_position added.

I have the following structure:

```
class Country < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :category_position

class Category < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :category_position

class CategoryPosition < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessible :country_id, :position, :category_id

  belongs_to :country
  belongs_to :category
```

I tried using

```
categories = Category.joins(:category_position)
        .where("category_positions.country_id = #{user.country.id}")
```

Which gives me all categories that have a position added for user country. How can I get the same list but also with all categories that don't have position added for user country?

Ideally this list should be ordered by position (1,2,3) then name (if equal positions) and at the end of the list categories with no positions.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this but I think you have to use **left outer join** and also **adjust the where clause**

for Rails 5

```
categories = Category.left_outer_joins(:category_position)
                     .where("category_positions.country_id = #{user.country.id} or category_positions.country_id is NULL")
```

for Rails 4 and earlier

```
categories = Category.joins("left outer join category_positions on category_positions.category_id = categories.id")
                     .where("category_positions.country_id = #{user.country.id} or category_positions.country_id is NULL")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried with adding `or category_positions.country_id is NULL` but it still only returns categories that have a position added. I tried `categories = Category.left_outer_joins(:category_position)
                     .where("category_positions.country_id is NULL")`  then it returns nothing. Even if I have several categories with no category_positions